# Why we need & in bind member function in boost?

Tags: c++, boost

In boost doc:

```
Binding member functions can be done similarly. A bound member function takes in a pointer or reference to an object as the first argument. For instance, given:

    struct xyz
    {
        void foo(int) const;
    };
    xyz's foo member function can be bound as:

    bind(&xyz::foo, obj, arg1) // obj is an xyz object
```

Why we need &xyz::foo, not just xyz::foo?

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
std::cout << bind(f, 1, 2)() << std::endl;
```

In this way, we don't use &.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address-of operator (i.e. `&`) is obligatory to get a pointer to member function. For [non-member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions) it's optional because of  [function-to-pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) implicit conversion.

> A pointer to function can be initialized with an address of a non-member function or a static member function. Because of the function-to-pointer implicit conversion, the address-of operator is optional: